# Where is DatabaseGeneratedAttribute Data Annotation?

Tags: .net, data-annotations, ef-code-first

...because it doesn't seem to be in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in that namespace, but was introduced in [Entity Framework 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Have you got that installed, and referenced `EntityFramework.dll` in your project?

Comment: Ahh.. perhaps not! Was trying to avoid referencing the data access technology from my domain project.